# Замена символов в строке Python

Tags: python

Условия: Пользователь вводит строку. Если она начинается на 'abc', заменить их на 'www', иначе добавить в конец строки 'qqq'.
Это все на что хватило.

```
text = input('Введите текст: ')
inds = [1, 2, 3]
new_text = ''
for i, s in enumerate(text, 1):
    if i in inds and "abc":
        new_text += 'w'
    else:
        new_text += 'q'[::3]
print(new_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Код:

```py
text = input()
if text.startswith('abc'):
    new_text = 'www' + text[3:]
else:
    new_text = text + 'qqq'
print(new_text)
```

Тесты:

```
abc111
www111
```

```
jjj
jjjqqq
```

Comment: Супер! все намного проще оказалось!

Comment: @Алексей, если вам помог этот ответ, отметьте его как принятый (серая галка слева)